# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException при перечислении массива в итераторе с увеличением шага перечисления

Tags: java, массивы, итераторы

У нас есть массив на 400 чисел: 0, 0.5,...199.5, 200. В итераторе этот массив перебирается и, в зависимости от указанной в main скорости перечисления (speed), меняется шаг итерации. Speed - число, которое будет прибавляться в классе-итераторе к index, от чего будет зависеть шаг перебора. Далее в консоль должен выводиться этот массив, но с другим шагом. Если в классе-итераторе указать `return pointList[index++],` то с итерацией проблем нет, но, при указании любого speed, даже равного 1, программа выкидывает ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 400 и указывает, что ошибка в строке класса-итератора:`return pointList[index += speed]` и в main в строке `System.out.println(iterator.next());`
Вот сижу, туплю, не могу разобраться, в чём дело. Поэтому, пожалуйста, дайте каких-нибудь наводок или намеков, в чем может быть проблема?

Полный код итератора:

```
public class PointIterator<Double> implements Iterator<Double> {
private int index;
private int speed;
private Double[] pointList;

public PointIterator(Double[] pointList){
    this.pointList = pointList;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    if(index < pointList.length){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public Double next() {
    if(this.hasNext()) {
        return pointList[index += speed];
    }else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

public void changeSpeed(int speed){
    this.speed = speed;
```

Фрагмент кода из main:

```
PointIterator iterator = harmonica.iterator(); //в классе Harmonica создаётся массив на 400 элементов и реализуется итератор, в нём проблем не наблюдается.
        iterator.changeSpeed(1); //сюда передаётся наше значение speed
        System.out.println("Array's length: " + harmonica.getPositionLength() + "\n");
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());                
        }
```

Comment: `if(index + speed < pointList.length)`, а не  `if(index < pointList.length)`. У вас реализация метода `hasCurrent()`, а не `hasNext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь

```java
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(index < pointList.length){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`hasNext()` будет возвращать `true` когда следующего элемента уже не будет. Например массив размером `10`. Его последний индекс `9`.

`hasNext()` для индекса `9` вернет `true`, потому что `9 < 10`, не смотря что элементов с индексом большим `9` не существует.

Кроме того, при определении наличия следующего элемента необходимо также учитывать шаг.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я так много внимания уделял тому, что выдавал компилятор, что не заметил очевидного.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще так делать нельзя. Разумеется, вы можете задать шаг (скорость). Проблема в том, метод next в итераторе не должен ничего проверять. Он должен возвращать следующий элемент. Для прверки есть метод hasNext. А теперь представьте ситуацию классического использования итератора :

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   //здесь я меняю шаг
   iterator.next();
}
```

В этом случае hasNext уже вернул true, для этого ему нужно знать шаг, однако в цикле вы его изменили (после проверки). Рано или поздно вы получите исключение. Мало того, ваши коллеги за такую "имплементацию" точно спасибо не скажут. Все знают, что такое итератор и каково его ожидаемое поведение. Поэтому имплементация итератора должна быть примерно такой:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PointIterator<Double> implements Iterator<Double> {

    private int cursor = 0;
    private int step;
    private int stepChanges;
    private final Double[] array;

    public PointIterator(Double[] array, int step) {
        this.step = step;
        this.stepChanges = step;
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        step = stepChanges;
        return cursor + step < array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Double next() {
        Double next = array[cursor];
        cursor += step;
        return next;
    }
    
    public void changeSpeed(int step){
        this.stepChanges = step;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ваши слова имеют смысл. Спасибо за совет)

Comment: @XenoProxy не за что. в принципе, если  очень надо менять шаг на ходу, то это тоже можно реализовать, но немного другим способом.

Comment: интересно, не подскажете этот способ или может дадите ссылку на примеры его реализации?

Comment: @XenoProxy подскажу, почему нет... в данной ситуации придется немного хитрить. с одной стороны нужно не выпадать за пределы ожидаемого поведения итератора, с другой - позволить менять шаг по ходу выполнения произвольное количество раз. самый простой способ, как по мне, заставить шаг меняться всегда перед фактической проверкой hasNext, независимо от того, когда произошел вызов соответствующего метода. в этом случае можно гарантировать корреткность работы при изменении шага (можно не бояться, что коллеги побьют в коридоре) и реализация достаточно простая и прозрачная. ответ я изменил.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо того, что hasNext() имеет не верное условие, о чем сказали в другом ответе, ещё и метод делает проверку без учета текущего шага, что может привести к вылету за пределы массива на этапе работы метода next() в момент внутренней проверки:

```
 if(this.hasNext()) {
        return pointList[index += speed];
 }
```

Что в общем-то можно исправить если уж делаете класс-обертку в методе hasNext(), но опять таки это действительно очень не интуитивная реализация метода.